# Run JBOSS-ESB code inside JBOSS application server

Tags: jboss-esb

Do anybody know how to run JBOSS-ESB code inside JBOSS application server in place of Jboss-esb application server?

Thanks for guidance!!
I followed those steps successfully. But when I start JBoss app server, I got some issues on console:

```
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@37d3acb2 { url=file:/C:/jboss-4.2.2.GA/serve
r/default/deploy/KvantumESB.esb/ }
  deployer: org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.config.JBoss4ESBDeployer@fb6763
 status: Deployment FAILED reason: No ClassLoaders found for: org.jboss.jms.ser
ver.destination.QueueService; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundExcept
ion: No ClassLoaders found for: org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService)
state: FAILED
watch: file:/C:/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/deploy/KvantumESB.esb/META-INF/j
boss-esb.xml
altDD: null
lastDeployed: 1322743787940
lastModified: 1322741590868
mbeans:
```

Any suggestions please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossesb/docs/4.10/manuals/html/Getting_Started_Guide/) there is described how to install JBoss ESB to JBoss application server. After installation you can deploy ESB applications to JBoss sever in common way.